# Making a JavaScript form that stores variables then prints them

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with this script (i am a complete js newbie) i need the script to store the text that a user types in into a js variable and then print it, this is what i have so far but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="Form Box">                   
    <form id="frm1" action="/action_page.php">
      Insult: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="forminput();">
    </form>
    <script>
      function othername() {
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        alert(input);
      }                 
      print(forminput)
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: its not working because in your button input the function you're calling is "forminput" but their is no function I see called that. If you want to call your `othername` function, replace the onClick event handler with othername so that it executes the function.

Comment: `forminput()` is not a function so on your button line, no action occurs when the onclick event fires

Comment: well not sure what you expect print() to do....

Comment: Don't add random tags to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with the script.

1. The `onclick` property is saying to call a function named `formInput`, but that function does not exist. Your script has a function called `othername`, so you want to use that instead.
2. The function `othername` tries to select an element with the id of `userInput`, but the input in your HTML does not have an `id` property.
3. Inside the `script` tag you are calling a function `print` which does not exist.

Here is a jsfiddle with your script updated and working: https://jsfiddle.net/grammar/c4yethp5/3/

And here is the updated code

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="Form Box">
    <form id="frm1" action="/action_page.php">
      Insult: <input type="text" name="fname" id="userInput"><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="othername();"  >
    </form>
    <script>
        function othername() {
          var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
          alert(input);
        }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from a HTML element the simplest way is to give the HTML element an `id`.

```
<input id="textinput" type="text" />
<input id="printbutton" type="button" value="Print">
```

when a user clicks the button:

```
// Get the text
var mytext = document.getElementById("textinput").value;

// Get the button
var btn = document.getElementById("printbutton");

// When the user clicks on the button print the text
btn.onclick = function () {
   alert(mytext);
}
```

To get an output with this text there are several options:

In chrome:

```
Console.log(mytext);
```

Get a popup:

```
alert(mytext);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ogj1ogs/3/